# Frequencies of combinaties of columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns that contain specific diseases. Here an example of a piece of it:

[image]

I want to make all possible combinations so I can check which combination of diseases mostly occur. So I want to make all combinations of 2 columns (A&B, A&C, A&D, B&C, B&D, C&D), but also combinations of 3 and 4 columns (A&B&C, B&C&D and so on). I have the following script for this:

```
from itertools import combinations

df.join(pd.concat({'_'.join(x): df[x[0]].str.cat(df[list(x[1:])].astype(str),
                                                 sep='')
                   for i in (2, 3, 4)
                   for x in combinations(df, i)}, axis=1))
```

But that generates a lot of extra columns in my dataset, and I still haven't got the frequencies of all combinations. This is the output that I would like to get:

[image]

What script can I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with aggregate join and last count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).value_counts()
print (s)
artritis,asthma                         2
cancer,artritis,heart_failure,asthma    1
cancer,heart_failure                    1
dtype: int64
```

If need 2 columns DataFrame:

```
df = s.rename_axis('vals').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
                                   vals  count
0                       artritis,asthma      2
1  cancer,artritis,heart_failure,asthma      1
2                  cancer,heart_failure      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
def index_agg_fn(x):
    x = [e for e in x if e != '']
    return ','.join(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cancer', 'cancer', None, None], 
                  'B': ['artritis', None, 'artritis', 'artritis'], 
                  'C': ['heart_failure', 'heart_failure', None, None], 
                  'D': ['asthma', None, 'asthma', 'asthma']})
df['count'] = 1
ptable = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(''), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], values=['count'], aggfunc='sum')
ptable.index = list(map(index_agg_fn, ptable.index))
print(ptable)
```

Result

```
                                         count
artritis,asthma                            2
cancer,heart_failure                       1
cancer,artritis,heart_failure,asthma       1
```